# Output for a linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

In this question, we are supposed to predict the output

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
def printLL(head):
    while head is not None:
        print(head.data,end=" ")
        head = head.next



node1 = Node(10)
node2 = Node(20)
node3 = Node(30)
node4 = Node(40)
node1.next = node2
node2.next = node3
node3.next = node4
printLL(node2)
```

Now what I can't seem to understand is when we call the function printLL(node2), then head is assigned the value node2, but node2 is a class instance, so how exactly does this work?

And in the line `while head is not None:`, what exactly are we comparing None with?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "then head is assigned the value node2, but node2 is a class instance, so how exactly does this work?" I don't understand why you are confused. Why should it matter? **Everything** is a "class instance" in Python. For example, `10` is an instance of the `int` class. "And in the line `while head is not None:`, what exactly are we comparing `None` with?" We are comparing it with `head`, which either `is None` or it isn't. I don't understand what is confusing here, either.

Comment: The list is *implied* by the links encoded in each `Node` instance's `next` attribute. Any `Node` instance you pass to `printLL` is, for that call, the head of a list, even if the node is contained in some *other* list with a different head.

Comment: What happened when you tried the code? Did you specifically expect something different to happen? Why?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel No I didn't get to the output. What I am trouble understanding is that the line `while head is not None` which means `while node 2 is not None` but node 2 has two attributes data and next so I cannot seem to understand what exactly are we comparing `None` with. I am a beginner in Python so it may be very kind of you to suggest what topic I must go through so that I understand this thoroughly.

Comment: "but node 2 has two attributes " That doesn't matter. Every object has attributes. (The methods are attributes, too.) "so I cannot seem to understand what exactly are we comparing None with" We are comparing it with **the entire object**. The question makes no sense; it is like asking "help, I don't understand what it means when we try to check whether Karl Knechtel is the president of the USA, *because people have organs*."

Comment: ... Just to make sure: you understand that `is` **does not mean** comparing the values of things to see if they are equal, right? Is that the actual question?